# Ruby on rails, table not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, quite new to Ruby, and trying to construct my first app. So far, gone well, but i recently had to reclone into it, and now that I try to log in, I keep getting an error, "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SessionsController#create

Could not find table 'users'". I checked the db and the table is there, I know it used to work and cant think why it's not working now. The error message is referring to to files, the session controller which has this bit to create session:

```
def create
  @user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if @user
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Inloggad!"
    session[:user] = @user
  else
    flash.now.alert = "losenord eller email stamde inte overens..."
    render "new"
  end
end
```

and this bit in the user model:

```
def self.authenticate(email, password)
  @user = find_by_email(email)
  if @user && @user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    @user
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Anyone with an inkling as to what could be the problem? Sorry if this is really dumb, as I am only just starting out and am not a brilliant programmer...

Answer (score 3):

Run the migrations (and seeds if any):

```
rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Comment: oh, am feeling very dumb right now... Thank you so much, that solved it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @eld If this solution worked for you, accept it as best answer.